# How to setup a filesystem mock to return DriveInfo information

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I am learning to mock the filesytem in unit test and have a simple method I want to test using mocks:

```
    public class FileStatsUtility
    {
        private IFileSystem _fileSystem;

        public FileStatsUtility(IFileSystem fileSystem)
        {
            _fileSystem = fileSystem;
        }

        public FileStatsUtility() : this(fileSystem: new FileSystem()) //use default implementation which calls System.IO
        {
        }

        public long GetFreeSpaceMb(string folder)
        {
            // returns the free space in Mb of the filesystem this folder is on
            string? driveName = Path.GetPathRoot(folder);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(driveName)) 
            {
                var drive = _fileSystem.DriveInfo.New(driveName);
                return drive.AvailableFreeSpace / (1024 * 1024);
            }
            else return -1;
        }
   }
```

I try to inject a mocked filesystem in the unit test

```
[TestMethod]
        public void ShouldReturnCorrectFreeSpaceMb ()
        {
            var testDir = "C:\anystring";
            var fsProviderMock = new Mock<IFileSystem>();
            var fsu = new FileStatsUtility(fsProviderMock.Object);

            //arrange
            fsProviderMock
                .Setup(m => m.DriveInfo.New(testDir))
                .Returns(new DriveInfo("C:\")
                {
                    DriveType = DriveType.Fixed,
                    AvailableFreeSpace = 500 * 1024 * 1024
                });

            //act
            var reportedFreeSpace = fsu.GetFreeSpaceMb(testDir);

            //assert
        }
```

This will not compile. DriveType and AvailableFreeSpace are read only. I think I miss something simple here, but cannot get my head around it.

How do I setup a mock to return a populated DriveInfo?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/TestableIO/System.IO.Abstractions

Answer (score 1):

For something as complex as a file system I would recommend making a regular class for your mocks rather than using a mocking framework. Mocking frameworks can be convenient if you need mocking small parts of a interface. But for something as complex as file system is likely better to just making your own class that simulates an in-memory file system. This will also be much easier to reuse for other types of tests.

I would also consider how you intend to use your file system. If you only want to store and retrieve data to you might consider something a little more abstract, like a `IFileRepository`, that does not concern itself with file system details like free space, or permissions. This should make it easier to make multiple implementations, and that makes the interface more useful.

If you simply create a thin wrapper around the windows file system there is a huge that you cannot feasibly make any other valid implementations due to all the various special behaviors that are difficult to replicate. Including mock implementations for tests. Consider for example,

- case sensitivity
- illegal file names and characters
- Max file name length
- Symbolic links
- etc...